# Dependency Management in AEM project POMs

Tags: maven, parent-pom, aem-6

In AEM project poms I have noticed that dependency name and versions are defined in the parent pom and it is not necessary to specify a version in child poms, as the version is managed at the Parent pom. And child poms only have dependencies defined. So, I am not clear on following.

1.If we already have dependencies defined in the parent pom with version no, then why do we need to define the same dependency back in child pom.xml (core/pom.xml in case of AEM).

Answer (score 0):

In Maven there is a difference between `<dependencies>` and `<dependencyManagement>`. Only the former really adds dependencies to your project, while the latter only defines the preferred version numbers (and scopes).